# Sum of traces of products of matrices in all permutations of a given set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

Say I have a set of finite number of positive (semi) definite matrices $\{A,B,C,\ldots, Z\}$.

Say we sort these matrices and take product in that order, and obtain a trace of the resulting matrix, e.g.

$$\operatorname{Tr}(ABC\cdots Z) $$

or

$$\operatorname{Tr}(ZYX\cdots A). $$
If the set size is $n$, then there are total $n!$ possible traces. Is there a simple expression for the sum of all of these possible traces?

Note that this is not limited to cyclic permutation of the matrix products, which will give a trivial result.

Comment: Say, we have only 3 matrices $A, B, C$ then sum of trace of all permutation should be $3(\mathrm{tr}(ABC) + \mathrm{tr}(ACB))$, I don't think it simplifies further, exactly what kind of expression are you looking for ?